# Unwanted black outline in Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, vector-graphics

I'm attempting to create an animated menu bar using raphael.js. It works fine in Firefox but in Chromium a black outline appears around the graphic. [View this jsFiddle in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/sTCSn/1/).

As the graphic moves it also seems to leave behind traces of this black outline as shown in the image below. I've tried setting the`"stroke-width"` attribute to `0` but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

[image: Raphael black outline problem]

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: Seems okay here in Chrome 20.0.1132.47 m

Comment: @SimpleCoder I'm using `Chromium 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04`. I've added a image to show the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Your browser is 2 versions outdated. Can you update and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: @SimpleCoder swish... was using Chromium instead of Chrome. Downloaded Chrome and it works fine now thanks.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Glad it works for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this problem and it's present in Chrome 18 and 19. As Chrome 20 is just a few days old, many users will still have previous versions installed, so it's still worth fixing it.

In Raphael just set your `stroke: none` or plain svg `element.setAttribute("stroke", "none")`

Comment: Yes, you are right, they right keyword is `none`. Answer updated.